# Regex to match for a string but only bringing a part of it by grouping

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string on the following form - for fiddle [see here](https://www.regex101.com/r/pR8pZ2/1).

> {[(0.3;0.43)(10;8.2)(0;0)(0.7888;12.345)]:8.56/13.9}

I would like to filter out just the coordinates in the parentheses. So, the pattern to match I've set up recognized a pair of parentheses (two backslashes for escaping the grouping). Then, it creates a group that on its inside has the minimal set of characters as long as they're separated by a semicolon and enclosed in parentheses. According to the debugger I have four matches, which suggest that it's correct. However, when I access *Grouping*, I see two elements - one containing a pair of brackets and one without.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\((.*?;.*?)\\)");
string full = regex.Matches(figure.ToString())[0].Value;
string with = regex.Matches(figure.ToString())[0].Groups[0].Value;
string sans = regex.Matches(figure.ToString())[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

I'm not entirely sure where the first group (*Groups[0]*) gets its information from. I suspect that I haven't phrased the regular expression well enough and that it actually react to the escaped parentheses as if it was a grouping as well. Am I right in my suspicion? How should I reformulate the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx:

> If the regular expression engine can find a match, the first element of the GroupCollection object (the element at index 0) returned by the Groups property contains a string that matches the entire regular expression pattern.

So `Groups[0]` has the entire value you matched (e.g. `(1;2)`), while `Groups[1]` is the first matched subgroup (e.g. `1;2`).

Comment: That's so unexpected and confusing... I see the docs at your link but still. What's the purpose of that? Is it useful in a way that I'm not comprehending, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Anything in parentheses is considered a group.  If you don't want the group to be considered in matches, you should prefix it with "?:"

(?:REGEX)

will cause the group to be ignored as a result, but still matched against

Comment: Not entirely sure how this relates to my question. Would you mind elaborating a bit so I can grasp the intended point, please?